# vscode-extension update virtual document

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I try to figure out, how to update a virtual document with my own custom Provider, which I have opened in an editor. I neither understand the docu at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/virtual-documents#update-virtual-documents nor the example at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/contentprovider-sample

I tried to hack something like the following:

```js
class MyProvider implements vscode.TextDocumentContentProvider {
  public onDidChangeEmitter = new vscode.EventEmitter<vscode.Uri>();
  onDidChange = this.onDidChangeEmitter.event;

  public static instance: LocalChangesProvider | undefined;
  public constructor() {
    LocalChangesProvider.instance = this;
  }

  provideTextDocumentContent(uri: vscode.Uri) {
    return someGlobal.text;
  }
}

someGlobal.text = 'other text';
MyProvider.instance.onDidChangeEmitter.fire(myUriSchema);
```

But it seems I am missing something. I am kind of frustrated, that I am too stupid to simply notify vscode to update my own virtual document :/ Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is `provideTextDocumentContent` ever called? Can you share a complete, minimal example?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, perhaps [embedded languages/request forwarding](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages#request-forwarding-sample) might be an alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working for a minimal full example I noticed, that the `myUriSchema` must match the title / path of the opened document, meaning:

```js
const documentUriToUpdate = vscode.Uri.parse(myUriSchema + ':' + myTitle);
MyProvider.instance.onDidChangeEmitter.fire(documentUriToUpdate )
```

P.S.:
From a design perspective this `instance`-hack of mine definitely wins no price - just for PoC how it works :)